# How to give xsd reference to an XML file

Tags: xml, xsd

Say I have an xml file `student.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<College>
<Student>
<name>John</Name>
<RollNo>1</RollNo>
</Student>
<Student>
<name>rosh</Name>
<RollNo>2</RollNo>
</Student>
</College>
```

Now how to add XSD reference for file `student.xsd` which is present in the same folder and validate the xml with it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to modify the XML document to include a reference to the schema. Every schema validator has some kind of API or user interface allowing you to say "validate document X against schema Y". The details depend on whether you are doing this from an application, from the command line, or from some interactive tool, which schema processor you are using, what platform you are running on, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Change in root element:

```
<College xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="student.xsd">
...
</College>
```

Comment: I am new to XML can you tell me what xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation means.??

Comment: In this case just path to `xsd schema` relative to your `xml document`. You can also check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757863.aspx)